# AngularJS - Swipe effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used the pager of AngularJS with Server Side coding. Basically what happens is when user clicks on NEXT the group of 5 records is displayed.

Now as the application is used in Tablets, i need swipe effect for this.

```
<section class="recent" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center" data-ng-init="recentUsers(1)">
                    <button type="button" class="rc-buttons" data-ng-repeat="user in recentusers">
                        {{user.firstname}}
                    </button>
                    <pager style="margin-top: -28px;" total-items="recenttotalItems" page="recentcurrentPage" items-per-page="recentitemsperpage" max-size="maxsize" on-select-page="recentUsers(page)" class="pagination-sm"
                        previous-text="<<" next-text=">>"></pager>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

How to implement swipe effect in AngularJS?

Comment: How abt down voting this question? Wt is wrong here?

Comment: According to the close-vote: _This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself._ (To be clear, I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: You should atleast try to implement a solution first your self, and if it fails come with a minimal example of what went wrong, so someone can help you. This is not an advice site. Search results offer lots of info on this topic.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I am asking for a solution here.....If i already have a solution, why should i come here.

Answer (score 2):

For handling swipes, you can use the **[`ngTouch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch)** module's **[ngSwipeLeft](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft)** and **[ngSwipeRight](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeRight)**.

Since it is a separate module, you need to include the script separately:

```
<script src=".../angular-touch.min.js"></script>
```

You, also, need to include the module as a dependency to you main module:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngTouch']);
```

Then you can use it to like this:

```
<div ng-swipe-right="doSomething()" ng-swipe-left="doSomethingElse()">
    ...
</div>
```